# ReadXML to vb.net datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, xmlreader

I am trying to get some XML from a REST API and display the data in a datagridview. Below is the code I have so far.

But when I open Form1 the datagridview is blank.

Is there a way I can validate if the data is being pulled back from the API.

Is there anything in my code that would prevent the data from being loaded into the datagridview.

Code:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Net

Public Class Form1

    Public Shared Sub DataSetSample1()

        Dim request As HttpWebRequest
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
        Dim dsWeather As DataSet

        Try
            ' Create the web request  
            request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create( _
             "https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/xml/Accounts/getRecords?authtoken=123456789&scope=crmapi"), HttpWebRequest)

            ' Get response  
            response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

            ' Load data into a dataset  
            dsWeather = New DataSet()
            dsWeather.ReadXml(response.GetResponseStream())


            Form1.DataGridView1.DataSource = dsWeather.Tables

        Finally
            If Not response Is Nothing Then response.Close()
        End Try


    End Sub
```

I should point out I am a novice :)

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: `dsWeather.Tables(0).Rows.Count` would tell you if how many rows were loaded.

Comment: I added "Form1.TextBox1.Text = dsWeather.Tables(0).Rows.Count" when I run my app it returns a value of 1 - But nothing is added to the view

Comment: I lie - It adds a column called "uri" with a value of "/crm/private/xml/Accounts/getRecords"

Comment: Are you sure the response is xml?  You might want to capture it to a string var and look at it.  Also, instead of a DataSet, all you need is a DataTable which will ReadXml as well.  Of course if the permissions are wrong or expired you'll get a notice (same as if you click on the link in your Q).

Comment: First you need to load the scheme (this will create columns and tables) and then load the xml (this will populate records into the DataSet Tables and Records)

Answer (score 0):

Reference the table you wish to display by index:

```
Form1.DataGridView1.DataSource = dsWeather.Tables(0)
```